# Information about Apply mining pool rewards ERC-20 Smart Contract

Tags: erc-20, ether, mining, ethereum-classic, usdt

I was contacted from a girl of Singapore,she told me to join a website,with 1k of buying USDT erc-20,every day I withdraw 30 dollar,but today I accept this partecipation for the claim the reward but nowhere was written that one time you accept if you don’t put the rest of money in my case 3674, they blocked for 180 days my money, how I to réclame my money, I contact them from the customer service of the website and send me to a telegram number service and they say I had to wait 180 days if I don’t put the rest of the money,what I have to do for to take back my 1325 USDT ? Help me

Comment: Sounds like pig butchering scam: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/155862/what-is-pig-butchering-scam

Answer (score 2):

You were not contacted by a girl from Singapore. You were contacted by a computer program pretending to be a girl from Singapore. The scammer operating the program then took over the conversation.

You cannot reclaim your money. Consider it lost. You've been scammed.

Beware, they will try to get more money out of you. They have added you to a list of victims and you will be contacted by more scammers, including people pretending to be able to get your money back. That's a scam too.

In the modern world you cannot assume that a person you haven't met even **exists**, let alone trust them to give you investment advice.

Sorry this happened to you.