# What is "pig butchering" scam?

Tags: security, scam

What is the "pig butchering" scam?  Why is it called "pig butchering"?  What are some of its elements?  How bad can it get?

Answer (score 2):

### The name

> The term pig butchering refers to an unsuspecting victim — the “pig” — being tricked by scammers into forking over money for a promised high rate of return.

> Scammers “fatten up the pig by getting the victim to think that they’re investing in something and get them to move money into cryptocurrency,”

> Once criminals “fatten up” their victims’ digital wallets, they steal the money...

### How the scam can start

> Scammers blast out millions of unsolicited messages each day to unsuspecting victims via text message and social media, often with an innocuous note like, “Hi, how are you?”

> The scammer operating under a false identity builds a relationship with the victim, sometimes over just a few weeks, before suggesting the victim “invest” in cryptocurrency.

### What the scam can lead to

> One technique involves assuring a victim that the scammer has made significant profits in cryptocurrency, persuading the victim they shouldn’t miss out on the benefits of cryptocurrency investments.

> Those who fall for the scam are coaxed into sending more and more money, and even provided with fictitious financial statements that make it appear their investments have made a substantial return.

More information at this source: https://www.cnn.com/2022/12/26/investing/crypto-scams-fbi-tips/index.html